# SVG not displaying in IE9

Tags: html, internet-explorer, svg

I have a document, written in HTML, that needs to be distributed and read from the local hard drive. The HTML contains img tags that reference SVGs on the local hard drive. This works fine in Firefox, but doesn't work at all in IE 9, just white space where the graphic should be. The version of IE is out of my control so that is what I have to work with. If I switch to a different graphic type, say PNG, it works fine. If I embed PNG image data inside the SVG it will be displayed as well. But if it is just an SVG, nothing. I recreated the issue with some simpler HTML and SVG:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Purpose: Test SVG Rendering in IE9</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">
        <!--meta charset="UTF-8"-->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Testing SVGs 5</h1>
        <p>SVG should render below:</p>
        <img src="sample.svg" alt="Sample SVG">
        <p>SVG should have rendered above. Works PNG below:</p>
        <img src="works-icon.png" alt="Sample PNG">
    </body>
</html>
```

And the SVG:

```
<svg width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
   <path d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z" />
</svg>
```

I have read as many of the similar questions as I could find, but so far no luck solving this problem.

Other useful information may be that IE is being run in Browser Mode IE9 and Document Mode of IE9 Standards. OS is Windows 7.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it work if you inline the svg directly?  I.e. replace the `img` tag with the block of svg?

Comment: That does work. Unfortunately, I solved the problem above by adding the W3C namespace URLs for SVG in the <svg> tag. I say unfortunate because that still solve my original problem which is harder to post. I may have to think about how to re-phrase my original question.

Comment: Thanks for the response, OldGeeksGuide.

Answer (score 1):

My problem ended up being 2-fold. My SVG needed namespace information like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg 
   width="300" 
   height="300" 
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   viewBox="0 0 300 300">
   <path d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z" />
</svg>
```

And the other problem came from the fact that the original document that caused the problem was using `<object>` tags instead `<img>` tags (so my original post was not an accurate representation of the full problem). IE9 will apparently allow you to add graphics of other formats to an HTML document via the `<object>` tag, but not SVG.

Comment: Thanks for the edits. I'm still learning some of the details of using this site.